# remove complete border from tables cells using css

Tags: html, css

I want to remove complete border from table cells as in shown in screen shot, i have to fill color in cells and there is white border are visible. how to make it complete remove.

[image]

It is simple table with 24 `td` tags and 2 `tr` tags, second `tr` tag containing `div` tags having background color red,blue, and gray.

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: `table * { border: none; }` this will remove border from table.

Comment: solve the issue by providing shadow of div inside each cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this CSS property, this will remove the border:-

```
table, th, td {

    border:none;
    border-collapse: collapse;

}
```